# List (and connect to) Bluetooth devices from within iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, external-accessory, mfi

I have a device that broadcasts data via bluetooth. It is MFI certified and I already have an application on the AppStore that communicates with it, using the External Accessory Framework.

The problem is that my application assumes the device is already paired.

Is there a way to enumerate all such devices within reach and allow the user to select (and therefore pair) to one of the devices in the list?

Comment: The MFI information is not public, so I don't think it can be discussed here unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do this unless two criteria are first met.

1. Your device must be a Bluetooth Low-Energy device.
2. The device must have the Bluetooth 4.0 integrated chip which, at the moment, is just the iPhone 4S and the New iPad.

These devices, if operating in the low-energy mode, can be discovered and paired through the [CoreBluetooth](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) framework.  There is no walk-through form of documentation on this framework, but if you are a seasoned iOS developer, you should be able to figure out how to use the framework through the cut-and-dry framework docs.

As mentioned, information regarding the MFi program and hardware development is locked down under an Apple NDA.  However, the information regarding pairing to these devices in this manner is readily available through information in Apple's own documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 6.0, they introduced `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:`

I haven't had much success with it (when it does find devices, they become lost a few seconds later, but this may be an issue with my code).

Comment: having the same issue. Need devices which are paired but not connected and connect with them. Has anyone figured a solution?