# Is it possible to implement this bluetooth feature in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am considering implementing in an app the bluetooth feature to read and display the battery life of a connected bluetooth peripheral (i.e. keyboard, headset...)

Is there an API or objects that can implement this in the iOS SDK or can someone tell me how this can be done, if it can be done ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but more than likely you will need to be a member of the Made for iOS program. You can connect to a device that is [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://mobworld.wordpress.com/tag/mfi-corebluetooth/) without being part of the MFi program but it only available for peripherals that support and the iOS device must be the iPhone 4S or the new iPad. Also reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775645/list-and-connect-to-bluetooth-devices-from-within-ios-app) stackoverflow question.